# XAMPP On Mac MySql Access Denied?

Tags: macos, xampp

I'm moving development from Vagrant (because it's too slow) to XAMPP on my mac. Everything is running fine with apache, and mysql server is running and phpmyadmin works fine when auth isn't enabled.

I have added a user, test with password test and granted privs on a database "test" which i can see in phpmyadmin is all set fine. However my IDE keeps saying access denied, and when i turn on http auth for phpmyadmin the user i setup also gives access denied there.

Not sure what's going on here, but this should be simple, i've added and granted access to the user as i normally would on any mysql server. Also xampp on a windows machine, fresh install all connects and logs in perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**:

---

1) First you have to find your sql port, In my case sql port is `3306`

[image]

---

2) Second go to the folder where **Xammp** is installed.

Then go the directory : `xampp/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`

Open the file `config.inc.php` in any text editor.

---

3) Find a line of code which looks something similar to this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

Change it to something like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3306';
```

Comment: I’m not having any issue with php my admin, my ide won’t connect to it, neither will any other MySQL management software. Seems php has no issues though. I’m also using a Mac not windows

Comment: Figured it out, it needed "localhost" as the hostname for the permissions.

Comment: My bad, I have taken your questiona in a whole new direction!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the permissions needed to be granted on "localhost" and not "%"